# Round up to 2 decimal places (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I want to round up the result of this to 2 decimal places. I already tried Math.floor*(Math.pow (1.02,7)*100)/100 But I get 1,150 instead of 1,148.69 - the answer I aim to be returned.

A snippet of my code atm:

```
function money (amount) {

  return amount*(Math.pow (1.02,7))
}

money(1000);
```

Comment: This may be a duplicate question. [Check the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary)

Comment: `Number.toFixed(2)` is what you need. Take note that a String is returned.

Comment: "*I get 1,150 instead of 1,148.69*" - I cannot reproduce.`Math.floor(Math.pow (1.02,7)*100)/100` does return the expected `1.14` for me. Notice that `1.14869` has 5 decimal places not just 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function money (amount) {
    return  Math.round(((amount*(Math.pow (1.02,7))) * 100)) / 100;
}
console.log(money(1000));
```

This will give the

Answer (score 3):

You can use `toFixed` to round to a certain decimal

```js
function money (amount) {

  return (amount*(Math.pow (1.02,7))).toFixed(2)
}

console.log(money(1000))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how `.toFixed()` is used:

```js
function money(amount){
  return (amount*Math.pow(1.02, 7)).toFixed(2);
}
console.log(money(1000));
```